# catalyst integret processmaker

Tags: plugins, workflow, catalyst

I am learning workflow project named processmaker, there is a plugin for ruby on rails named processmaker.gem.

Is there another plugin for perl catalyst there?

Or is there another workflow project open source and  free for perl catalyst? The workflow project should have web ui to define work flow.

Comment: <p>No one can give some advice?</p>

Answer (score 0):

We don't have anything for Catalyst. But you can always work on an integration between your catalyst application and ProcessMaker using webservices. http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/ProcessMaker_WSDL_Web_Services

Please let me know if this helps and/or if you need further information

Regards

---